# How to prove $\langle u,v\rangle=\frac{1}{4}||u+v||^2-\frac{1}{4}||u-v||^2+\frac{i}{4}||u+iv||^2-\frac{i}{4}||u-iv||^2$?

Tags: linear-algebra

$\langle\boldsymbol{u}+\boldsymbol{v}\rangle= \frac{1}{4}||\boldsymbol{u}+\boldsymbol{v}||^2-\frac{1}{4}||\boldsymbol{u}-\boldsymbol{v}||^2+\frac{i}{4}||\boldsymbol{u}+i\boldsymbol{v}||^2-\frac{i}{4}||\boldsymbol{u}-i\boldsymbol{v}||^2$ where $\boldsymbol{u},\boldsymbol{v}$ are vectors in complex inner product space and $i^2=-1.$
\begin{align}
 &\frac{1}{4}||\boldsymbol{u}+\boldsymbol{v}||^2-\frac{1}{4}||\boldsymbol{u}-\boldsymbol{v}||^2+\frac{i}{4}||\boldsymbol{u}+i\boldsymbol{v}||^2-\frac{i}{4}||\boldsymbol{u}-i\boldsymbol{v}||^2\notag\\
   &=\frac{1}{4}(\langle\boldsymbol{u}+\boldsymbol{v},\boldsymbol{u}+\boldsymbol{v}\rangle^{1/2})^2-\frac{1}{4}(\langle\boldsymbol{u}-\boldsymbol{v},\boldsymbol{u}-\boldsymbol{v}\rangle^{1/2})^2+\frac{i}{4} (\langle\boldsymbol{u}+i\boldsymbol{v},\boldsymbol{u}+i\boldsymbol{v}\rangle^{1/2})^2-\frac{i}{4} (\langle\boldsymbol{u}-i\boldsymbol{v},\boldsymbol{u}-i\boldsymbol{v}\rangle^{1/2})^2 \notag\\
   &=\frac{1}{4}\langle\boldsymbol{u}+\boldsymbol{v},\boldsymbol{u}+\boldsymbol{v}\rangle-\frac{1}{4}\langle\boldsymbol{u}-\boldsymbol{v},\boldsymbol{u}-\boldsymbol{v}\rangle+\frac{i}{4} \langle\boldsymbol{u}+i\boldsymbol{v},\boldsymbol{u}+i\boldsymbol{v}\rangle-\frac{i}{4} \langle\boldsymbol{u}-i\boldsymbol{v},\boldsymbol{u}-i\boldsymbol{v}\rangle \notag\\
   &=
 \end{align} Then I do not know how to do it.

Comment: You know that the inner product is a sesquilinear form

Comment: It is superfluous to take square roots and square again —that is, it’s simply $\|u+v\|^2=\langle u+v\,,u+v\rangle$. For the remainder use the other axioms of inner product, that is, $$\langle u+v,w\rangle= \langle u,w\rangle+ \langle v,w\rangle\,.$$ $$\overline{\langle u,v\rangle}= \langle v,u\rangle$$ and $$\langle iu,v,\rangle= i\langle u,v\rangle$$

Comment: how to use the second axiom you pointed out?

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a typo. However, we can prove that if $u:=x$ and $v:=y$, $$\langle x,y \rangle=\frac{1}{4}\sum_{k=1}^{4}i^{k}|| x+i^{k}y||$$
if the field scalar $\mathbb{F}=\mathbb{C}$ and $i^{2}=-1$.

Now, for to prove this fact we can see that
\begin{eqnarray}
||x+i^{k}y||^{2}&=&||x||^{2}+2Re\langle x,i^{k}y \rangle +||i^{k}y||^{2}\\
&=&||x||^{2}+2Re[\overline{i^{k}}\langle x,y \rangle] +||y||^{2}
\end{eqnarray}
Now, assuming that $\langle x,y\rangle=a+bi$, with $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$, so we can see that RHS would be
\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{1}{4}\left[ ||x||^{2}\sum_{k=1}^{4}i^{k}+2\sum_{i=1}^{4}i^{k}Re[\overline{i^{k}}\langle x,y \rangle]+||y||^{2}\sum_{i=1}^{4}i^{k}\right]&=&\frac{1}{2}(ib+(-a)(-1)+(-b)(-i)+a)\\
&=&a+ib\\
&=&\langle x,y \rangle
\end{eqnarray}

Answer (score 1):

Lemma 1
If $\boldsymbol{u},\boldsymbol{v},\boldsymbol{w}\in V$ where $V$ is a complex inner product space, then complex inner product have the following property $$\langle\boldsymbol{u},\boldsymbol{v}+\boldsymbol{w}\rangle=\langle\boldsymbol{u},\boldsymbol{v}\rangle+\langle\boldsymbol{u},\boldsymbol{w}\rangle.$$
proof
$$\langle\boldsymbol{u},\boldsymbol{v}+\boldsymbol{w}\rangle=\overline{\langle\boldsymbol{v}+\boldsymbol{w},\boldsymbol{u}\rangle}=\overline{\langle\boldsymbol{v},\boldsymbol{u\rangle}+\langle\boldsymbol{w},\boldsymbol{u}\rangle}=\overline{ \overline{\langle\boldsymbol{u},\boldsymbol{v}\rangle}+\overline{\langle\boldsymbol{u},\boldsymbol{w}\rangle}}=\langle\boldsymbol{u},\boldsymbol{v}\rangle+\langle\boldsymbol{u},\boldsymbol{w}\rangle.$$

Lemma 2
If $\boldsymbol{u},\boldsymbol{v}\in V$ where $V$ is a complex inner product space, $k\in \mathbb C,$ then complex inner product have the following property $$\langle\boldsymbol{u},k\boldsymbol{v}\rangle=\bar k\langle\boldsymbol{u},\boldsymbol{v}\rangle $$
proof
$$\langle\boldsymbol{u},k\boldsymbol{v}\rangle=\overline{\langle k\boldsymbol{v},\boldsymbol{u}\rangle}=\bar k\overline{\langle\boldsymbol{v},\boldsymbol{u}\rangle}=\bar k\langle\boldsymbol{u},\boldsymbol{v}\rangle.$$
proof
We apply 2 lemmas above to obtain \begin{align}
 &\frac{1}{4}||\boldsymbol{u}+\boldsymbol{v}||^2-\frac{1}{4}||\boldsymbol{u}-\boldsymbol{v}||^2+\frac{i}{4}||\boldsymbol{u}+i\boldsymbol{v}||^2-\frac{i}{4}||\boldsymbol{u}-i\boldsymbol{v}||^2\notag\\
   &=\frac{1}{4}(\langle\boldsymbol{u}+\boldsymbol{v},\boldsymbol{u}+\boldsymbol{v}\rangle^{1/2})^2-\frac{1}{4}(\langle\boldsymbol{u}-\boldsymbol{v},\boldsymbol{u}-\boldsymbol{v}\rangle^{1/2})^2+\frac{i}{4} (\langle\boldsymbol{u}+i\boldsymbol{v},\boldsymbol{u}+i\boldsymbol{v}\rangle^{1/2})^2-\frac{i}{4} (\langle\boldsymbol{u}-i\boldsymbol{v},\boldsymbol{u}-i\boldsymbol{v}\rangle^{1/2})^2 \notag\\
   &=\frac{1}{4}\langle\boldsymbol{u}+\boldsymbol{v},\boldsymbol{u}+\boldsymbol{v}\rangle-\frac{1}{4}\langle\boldsymbol{u}-\boldsymbol{v},\boldsymbol{u}-\boldsymbol{v}\rangle+\frac{i}{4} \langle\boldsymbol{u}+i\boldsymbol{v},\boldsymbol{u}+i\boldsymbol{v}\rangle-\frac{i}{4} \langle\boldsymbol{u}-i\boldsymbol{v},\boldsymbol{u}-i\boldsymbol{v}\rangle \notag\\
   &=\frac{1}{4}(\langle\boldsymbol{u},\boldsymbol{u}\rangle+\langle \boldsymbol{u},\boldsymbol{v}\rangle+\langle \boldsymbol{v},\boldsymbol{u} \rangle+\langle\boldsymbol{v},\boldsymbol{v} \rangle)-\frac{1}{4}(\langle\boldsymbol{u},\boldsymbol{u} \rangle+\langle\boldsymbol{u},-\boldsymbol{v} \rangle+\langle-\boldsymbol{v},\boldsymbol{u}\rangle+\langle-\boldsymbol{v},-\boldsymbol{v} \rangle )\notag \\
   &+\frac{i}{4}(\langle\boldsymbol{u},\boldsymbol{u} \rangle+\langle\boldsymbol{u},i\boldsymbol{v} \rangle+\langle i\boldsymbol{v},\boldsymbol{u} \rangle+\langle i\boldsymbol{v},i\boldsymbol{v} \rangle )-\frac{i}{4}(\langle\boldsymbol{u},\boldsymbol{u} \rangle+\langle\boldsymbol{u},-i\boldsymbol{v} \rangle+\langle-i\boldsymbol{v},\boldsymbol{u} \rangle+\langle-i\boldsymbol{v},-i\boldsymbol{v} \rangle )\notag\\
   &=\frac{1}{4}(\langle\boldsymbol{u},\boldsymbol{u}\rangle+\langle \boldsymbol{u},\boldsymbol{v}\rangle+\langle \boldsymbol{v},\boldsymbol{u} \rangle+\langle\boldsymbol{v},\boldsymbol{v} \rangle)-\frac{1}{4}(\langle\boldsymbol{u},\boldsymbol{u} \rangle+(\overline{-1})\langle\boldsymbol{u},\boldsymbol{v} \rangle+(-1)\langle\boldsymbol{v},\boldsymbol{u}\rangle+(-1)(\overline{-1})\langle\boldsymbol{v},\boldsymbol{v} \rangle )\notag \\
   &+\frac{i}{4}(\langle\boldsymbol{u},\boldsymbol{u} \rangle+(\bar i)\langle\boldsymbol{u},\boldsymbol{v} \rangle+i\langle \boldsymbol{v},\boldsymbol{u} \rangle+(i)(\bar i)\langle \boldsymbol{v},\boldsymbol{v} \rangle )-\frac{i}{4}(\langle\boldsymbol{u},\boldsymbol{u} \rangle+(\overline{-i} )\langle\boldsymbol{u},\boldsymbol{v} \rangle+(-i)\langle\boldsymbol{v},\boldsymbol{u} \rangle+(-i)(\overline{-i})\langle\boldsymbol{v},\boldsymbol{v} \rangle )\notag\\
   &=\frac{1}{4}(\langle\boldsymbol{u},\boldsymbol{u}\rangle+\langle \boldsymbol{u},\boldsymbol{v}\rangle+\langle \boldsymbol{v},\boldsymbol{u} \rangle+\langle\boldsymbol{v},\boldsymbol{v} \rangle)-\frac{1}{4}(\langle\boldsymbol{u},\boldsymbol{u} \rangle-\langle\boldsymbol{u},\boldsymbol{v} \rangle-\langle\boldsymbol{v},\boldsymbol{u}\rangle+\langle\boldsymbol{v},\boldsymbol{v} \rangle )\notag \\
   &+\frac{i}{4}(\langle\boldsymbol{u},\boldsymbol{u} \rangle-i\langle\boldsymbol{u},\boldsymbol{v} \rangle+i\langle \boldsymbol{v},\boldsymbol{u} \rangle+\langle \boldsymbol{v},\boldsymbol{v} \rangle )-\frac{i}{4}(\langle\boldsymbol{u},\boldsymbol{u} \rangle+i\langle\boldsymbol{u},\boldsymbol{v} \rangle-i\langle\boldsymbol{v},\boldsymbol{u} \rangle+\langle\boldsymbol{v},\boldsymbol{v} \rangle )\notag\\
   &=\frac{1}{2}\langle\boldsymbol{u},\boldsymbol{v}\rangle+\frac{1}{2}\langle\boldsymbol{v},\boldsymbol{u}\rangle-\frac{i}{2}i\langle\boldsymbol{u},\boldsymbol{v} \rangle+\frac{i}{2}i\langle\boldsymbol{v},\boldsymbol{u}\rangle\notag\\
   &=\frac{1}{2}\langle\boldsymbol{u},\boldsymbol{v}\rangle+\frac{1}{2}\langle\boldsymbol{v},\boldsymbol{u}\rangle+\frac{1}{2}\langle\boldsymbol{u},\boldsymbol{v} \rangle-\frac{1}{2}\langle\boldsymbol{v},\boldsymbol{u}\rangle\notag\\
   &=\langle\boldsymbol{u},\boldsymbol{v}\rangle.\notag
 \end{align}